# Docusign API - Views/Recipient with In Person Signing

Tags: javascript, docusignapi

I have everything working for the views/sender, and I have envelopeId/recipients working - so I know every piece of data that I think I need.

In my envelope I have 2 inPersonSigners.  The first is a "client" always, and the second is an employee, always.

I have the UserId, RecipientGuid, RecipientId, UserName, etc.  Since these are In Person AND Embedded signers, they do not have email addresses.

I have been unable to get the recipient view to return the URL because the "UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT" OR "INVALID_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT" errors I am receiving with every combination of data I have tried.

In the documentation it states you only need the clientUserId or a userName and Email combination.  I have tried a variety of these, and still cant get the in person, embedded signing recipient view to return the correct response.  100% of the time it is an envelope recipient invalid error.  I have tested every combination I can think of in postman and code;

inPersonSigners
[0]

```
clientUserId:"SomeoneHelpfulsomeonehelpful@stackexchange.com"
hostEmail:"someonehelpful@stackexchange.com"
hostName:"StackExchange User"
note:""
recipientId:"1"
recipientIdGuid:"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b65d-3bb23fbf8860"
requireIdLookup:"false"
roleName:"1"
routingOrder:"1"
signerEmail:""
signerName:"Test Testeroni"
status:"sent"
userId:"xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-913e-c347a9f2dafd"
```

I just need to be able to take the data above, post to /views/recipient and get the response url.

I think the problem is that when this document template is being created, via Drawloop ->Docusign, there is no Email being passed, but there is a Name and clientUserId.  Hopefully its something simple that I have missed after looking at the same thing for hours.

Comment: I should note that I have found ~10 questions here, and tried each variation of them, none of which have worked.  My combination is EMBEDDED signing, IN PERSON signers.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The below sample invocation/POST would work. I did notice that your clientUserID resembles an email@ - typically this value is in a GUID format. Something to keep in mind.

POST 
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/459963/envelopes//views/recipient

```
{
  "authenticationMethod":"email",
  "username": "StackExchange User",
  "email": "someonehelpful@stackexchange.com",
  "returnUrl":"http://www.something_you_provide.com",
  "clientUserId":"SomeoneHelpfulsomeonehelpful@stackexchange.com"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Luis. I need the userId, clientUserId method since my inpersonsigners don't have an email address as part of their recipient records.

Comment: The email@ provided in the POST should be the email@ of the HOST (which absolutely has an email@).